# Azure AD Custom Security Attributes & Dynamic Groups

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to build dynamic groups that would be populated by a rule checking customSecurityAttributes. I can add the attribute to a user, I can see the attribute in the GUI in Azure AD, but I am not able to pull the attribute via PowerShell or Graph API. The results show "null."

Graph API Query: **https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$Select=customSecurityAttributes**

Result:
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(customSecurityAttributes)/$entity",
"customSecurityAttributes": null
}

Comment: I believe I may have found  my own answer...at current (5/13/22) Azure AD doesn't allow dynamic group population based on customSecurityAttributes. If anybody has an update, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Ryan , there were couples of question ,1) .  have you tried to check the dynamic group you created exist in ADO side? . 2 ) have you tried in graph explore or PowerShell without odata context, are you able to see the select attributes ? and last what process you followed to create the dynamic group ?

Comment: The odata context showed up without my input. As you can see above, my Graph API query doesn't call for it...I'd be interested in learning how I could pull it without the odata context.

Comment: I did verify the dynamic group in the Azure does exist. The primary issue is that the configuration of the group rules does not allow me to pull the CSA data from the fields allowed within the rule builder.

Comment: The dynamic group was created in Azure AD, by selecting Groups > New Group, Group Type: Security, and then changing the Membership Type dropdown to "Dynamic User"

Answer (score 0):

you are right , custom security group is only supported for users (only in preview) - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-custom-security-attributes.md , if you want this feature you will create a new feature request - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform